# Image fills up the whole space on Safari mobile

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, safari, tailwind-css

So my site's navbar shows up differently on Android and iOS phone, [on Chrome/Android it looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9k7.jpg) but for some reason, [the hamburger icon got stretched out and covers the whole page on Safari/iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6NnI.jpg).

I use TailwindCSS and here's my code:

```
        <nav className="fixed sticky top-0 z-10 flex gap-2 p-2 bg-white cursor-pointer md:pl-4">
            <img
                onClick={toggleOpen}
                src="/hamburger-menu-red.png" className="w-10" alt="menu"
            />

            {props.showLogo && (
                <Link to="/">
                    <img
                        src="/cooken-logo.png" alt="cooken-logo" className="w-20 cursor-pointer" />
                </Link>
            )}
        </nav>
```

Is it because I don't specify the height of the hamburger icon or is it some compatibility issue with Safari? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update based on Seth's input**

```
        <nav className="fixed sticky top-0 z-10 flex items-center h-12 gap-2 p-2 bg-white md:pl-4">
            <button
                onClick={toggleOpen}
            >
                <img
                    src="/hamburger-menu-red.png" className="w-10 h-8" alt="menu"
                />
            </button>

            {props.showLogo && (
                <Link to="/">
                    <img
                        src="/cooken-logo.png" alt="cooken-logo" className="w-16 h-8"
                    />
                </Link>
            )}
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is the child of a flex item and the default align-items property of flex items is stretch.

However, there are other issues that are more of concern with your code, it is invalid. Neither an image of a hamburger or a site logo are justifiable nav items. A nav element should contain navigation links to site pages.

You should not attach a click event to an image. An image element is just for showing an image, nothing else. If it *goes somewhere* use a link, if it *does something* use a button element.

You don't need to put cursors on links, they already have them; images don't because they are not interactive elements.

I would suggest that the best approach is to use a button elemement (which already comes with clicky behaviours built in) to reveal a list of links (which come with linky behaviours built in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added `h-12` and `items-center` now to the nav element. Is it sufficient? And I refactored the code based on your input (check post's update 1).